# Home page with Polylang redirects to other page

Tags: url-rewriting, redirect

On my website : https://www.littleguestcollection.com/, the homepage is redirected to other page (this one : https://www.littleguestcollection.com/fr/hotels/lux-tamassa/).

I have no idea what is the problem, I updated my permalink settings to update the cache, I removed WP Rocket, I try some changes in PolyLang.

Does anyone know what can be the problem ? I don't know where to search.

Comment: As far as i know, the plugin polylang is redirecting to the translated pages. You can try deactivating it and then check whether it is caused by it. It is not permalink error or other thing.

Comment: Are you in France or have your computer/browser language settings set to French? When I went there, it redirected me to the English page.

Comment: Have you checked if this is deactivated? In Wordpress Backend -> Languages -> Settings -> Detect browser language